# mput Not Transferring All Files During FTP Transfer

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, ftp

I'm having issues with my Unix FTP script...

It's only transferring the **first three** files in the directory that I'm local cd'ing into during the FTP session.

Here's the bash script that I'm using:

```
#!/bin/sh
YMD=$(date +%Y%m%d)
HOST='***'
USER='***'
PASSWD=***
FILE=*.png
RUNHR=19
ftp -inv ${HOST} <<EOF
quote USER ${USER}
quote PASS ${PASSWD}
cd /models/rtma/t2m/${YMD}/${RUNHR}/
mkdir /models/rtma/t2m/${YMD}/
mkdir /models/rtma/t2m/${YMD}/${RUNHR}/
lcd /home/aaron/grads/syndicated/rtma/t2m/${YMD}/${RUNHR}Z/
binary
prompt
mput ${FILE}
quit
EOF
exit 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you cd'ing to a directory and then trying to create it in the next step? Wouldn't it be better to create it before you try to go there? Or have I misread it?

Comment: How about adding "!pwd" and "!ls" before your "mput" to make sure you are where you think you are?

Comment: If it's a bash script, how about putting that in the shebang so future readers & maintainers know you are expecting bash features?

Comment: are the filenames you're putting strictly alpha-numeric names with no spaces or UTF8 chars, etc in them? Some ftp clients have limits to # of files that can be processed in 1 `mput`, or in 1 case I dealt with, the total length of the "words" that would compose your $FILE variable. I'd be surprised if thats true about ubuntu, but it may be your receiving system has limitations. You may have to experiment some to figure it out. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone! I'm going to try experimenting with sftp and/or scp and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered same issue, I have to transfer 400K files but mput * or mput *.pdf was not moving all files in one go
tried timeout :fails
tried -r recursive :fails
tried increasing Data/control timeout in IIS :fails
tried -i
Prompt
scripting fails

Finally went to use portable filezilla connect to from source and transferred the all files

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30359210)